# Не переходит на созданные страницы

Tags: php

Добрый день. Я у меня самописаный сайт на php. И не переходит на другие страницы, хотя они есть. Выходит ошибка 404  страница не найдена. Этот код из файла типо index.php

```
            <li class="<?php if(isset($activeLink['home']['welcome'])) echo "active" ?>"><a href="<?php echo site_url() ?>">Home</a></li>
        <?php if($this->user->loggedin) : ?>
          <li class="<?php if(isset($activeLink['home']['general'])) echo "active" ?>"><a href="<?php echo site_url('dashboard') ?>">Dashboard</a></li>
        <?php else : ?>
          <li class="<?php if(isset($activeLink['account']['register'])) echo "active" ?>"><a href="<?php echo site_url("register") ?>">Register</a></li>
```

Comment: Пишите с помощью MVC структуры?

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста функцию site_url() и массив $activeLink P.S. не увидел. Вы скажем так дали фасад и сказали расскажи мне что не так в фундаменте

Comment: @AlexMorgenshtern я не знаю. Я купил сайт. где должны быть $activeLink и site_url()?
Сейчас попробую поискать

Comment: @AlexMorgenshtern
Я вас прекрасно понимаю) Сейчас попробую понять

Comment: @AlexMorgenshtern
можно с вами связаться чтобы Вы сами посмотрели этот файл?

Comment: Да я есть в скайпе, телеграме viber'е

Comment: @AlexMorgenshtern 
Это?











function site_url($uri = '', $protocol = NULL)
 {
  return get_instance()->config->site_url($uri, $protocol);
 }

Comment: Относительно а массив $activeLink? Мой скайп:Orest Ganulyak(Nalleas)

Comment: @AlexMorgenshtern не ищет вас
http://take.ms/KXeTv

Comment: Напиши свой скайп

Comment: me2life - мой скайп